# Toggle on an faq page

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an onclick toggle function with divs. I'll show an example for one of them:

```
<div id="question1">
<a href="#" style="color: #FFF"
onclick="toggle('answer1');">Can I access my work from home?</a>
</div>

<div style="display:none" id="answer1">
You can't access you University drive from home, it is advised to back up your work onto a cloud such as Google Drive or Dropbox. You can however access your tasks and see what deadlines you have to meet using something called Blackboard.
</div>
```

So when I click on the first question the first answer shows, I just want to know how to hide is when I click on question 2? So in the end it isn't possible for 2 answers to be shown at once.

Answer (score 0):

Give the answer divs a class (such as `answers`) to identify them as a group, then do something like below, to hide all of the answers, each time `toggle()` is fired.

```
function toggle(id){
   var answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answers');
   for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++){
      answers[i].style.display = 'none';
   }

   // show the target
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```